# Возможность использования хэштэгов в описании (Open Graph) к кнопкам "Facebook поделиться" и "Вконтакте поделиться"?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно (и можно ли) проставить хэштэги в текст описания (или к самому прикреплённому изображению) к шарингу Вконтакте и Facebook?

Важно, чтобы после самих шарингов социальные сети воспринимали тексты описаний (или прикрепленное к шарингу изображение с установленным хэштэгом) и могли выделять хэштэги в них, делая ссылками.

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Вконтакт умеет парсить хэштэги в заголовке:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Заголовок страницы #hashtag" />
```

Фейсбук такого не умеет, зато позволяет указать хэштег параметром ссылки для поделения:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?src=sp&u=https%3A%2F%2Fya.ru&hashtag=%23hashtag
```

Блок "Поделиться" пока не знает об этом параметре, но скоро мы его научим.

Comment: Был бы признателен, если бы Вы уточнили кто "мы"?

Comment: В данном случае -- я.

Comment: Множественное местоимение. Предположил что вы из команды этих/одной_из сетей.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Скажите пожалуйста, я правильно вас понял, что при создании кода шарингов, чтобы они были видны пользователям социальной сети, необходимо: 1) К кнопке вконтакте дописать укаанный код 2) Добавить параметр хэштэга для facebook? В этом случае: 1) Вконтакте сделает нужное слово заголовка шаринга активным хэштэгом 2) Facebook допишет к заголовку шаринга хэштэг Вопрос не только в технической части, но и в том, чтобы пользователь увидел хэштэги и смог по ним кликнуть. Заранее спасибо за ваш развернутый комментарий, Роман!

Comment: Давайте по порядку. Шаг первый – добавить хэштэги в элемент `og:title` opengraph-разметки страницы. Если поделиться такой страницей во Вконтакте, тэги распарсятся и по ним можно будет кликнуть. Плохо, что в Facebook эти тэги тоже будут видны, но как простой текст.

Comment: Шаг второй – дождаться, когда в блок Поделиться добавят возможность указывать хэштег для Facebook. Тогда можно будет настроить блок подобным образом: `<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook" data-hashtag:facebook="myhashtag"></div>`.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Роман, спасибо большое за ваш развернутый ответ.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Роман, спасибо большое за ваш развернутый ответ. Буквально еще 2 вопроса: 1) Скажите пожалуйста, а прикрепление изображений к шарингам facebook. vk и twiter может быть в формате gif? Или социальные сети не пропустят такое изображение от "вырежут" его из шаринга? 2) Использование хэштэгов с ограничением поиска (как вконтакте) #тэг@группа будет отображать пользователю все репосты пользователей, сделанные с данным хэштэгом или ограничится только постами указанной группы? Можно ли использовать хэштэги такого вида (#тэг@группа) в facebook?Заранее еще спасибо за ваш ответ, Роман.

Comment: @Timofey 1. За все соцсети не скажу, но во Вконтакте, например, можно. 2. Ох, тут не подскажу, с такими особенностями хэштегов я не знаком.

Answer (score 0):

уже никак(

отменили хештеги
даже из заголовков все выпиливают